# Two loop in one code

Tags: vba, excel, calendar

I could use some assistance correcting the code below as what show when activated is the first image while I want to do the second image.

Also if you have other code to do the same job, please do. thanks in advance for your assistance.

[image]

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
   Dim a As Range, az As Range
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set rng = Range("A2:AE2")
   Set az = Range("A3:AE6")
   For Each cell In rng
     For Each a In az
       If cell.Value = "Fri" Then
         a.Value = "Fri"
       ElseIf cell.Value = "Sat" Then
         a.Value = "Sat"
       End If
     Next a
   Next cell
   Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the { and the } in the styling/headers section, above where you type,  to insert formatted code next time please so that it looks like this. :)

Edited with your answer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim a As Range, az As Long 'set az = number of rows you want filled with fri/sat
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Set rng = Range("A2:AE2")
  az = 4
  For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "fri" Then
      For i = 1 To az
        cell.Offset(i).Value = "fri"
      Next i
    ElseIf cell.Value = "sat" Then
      For i = 1 To az
        cell.Offset(i).Value = "sat"
      Next i
    End If
  Next cell
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry Rodger, while your code tell what I want but when trying it, gave no result.

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean it didn't give a result. Is it not doing everything you want? Is it giving an error? What does the output look like? It is working when I run it.

Comment: oh, thank you Rodger, I realized where was the problem, the code not worked due to the small letters of "Fri" & "Sat", but after I changed yours to Capital letter it work greatly. thanks my friend and sorry for not realizing this.

Comment: dear Rodger, one more assistance please, I want to use the same code you give but with one additional to it if you do not mind. I want the code work based on the column ("A") if not blank then to continue but if it reach to blank, then to stop at the last filled out row.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want it to stop as soon as there is a blank in column A, even if that row isn't blank in other columns? if that is right change your AZ=4 to az = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Comment: hi Rodger, I changed AZ = 4 to az = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row but not worked at the begining till I removed the "sht" as it shows erro, and it works but for two rows only while the other filled rows 5,6, 7 in A is not blank. so please advise if you do not mind

Comment: post your updated code? oops, sorry, yeah, I left sht. in there and should have pulled it.

Comment: Also, change it to this. I just realized if you are starting on A2 you don't want the row count to be the counter. You want it 2 less. az = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 2

Comment: thanks Rodger, it works very well. appreciate it friend

Comment: NP. Canyou hit the green check and accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Hi Rodger, I did so if you mean the tap in above this page, but if other please let me know where it is to do so. thank Rodger

Answer (score 1):

You get the result because you do it for each cell in az, but you dont wan't to do it so, you have to fill just the column of the found Fri or Sat.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Set rng = Range("B2:BE2")
   For Each cell In rng
     If cell.value = "Fri" Then
       For i as Integer = 3 To 6 Step 1
         Cells(i,cell.column).Value = "Fri"
       Next
     End If

     If cells.value = "Sat" Then
       For i as Integer = 3 To 6 Step 1
         Cells(i,cell.column).Value = "Sat"
       Next
     End If

   Next cell
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It should be something like that i think

Comment: not work also flohdieter, it shows error, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>Also if you have other code to do the same job, please do.</sup>

The following will ask to build a new calendar worksheet based upon the current month every time you create a new worksheet.

[image: thisworkbook]
    **[ThisWorkbook code sheet:](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If MsgBox("Create new calendar?", vbYesNo, "AutoBuild") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    'the following DELETES ANY WORKSHEET WITH THE SAME MONTH/YEAR NAME
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(Format(Date, "mmm yyyy")).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    'create a new calendar worksheet based on the current month
    With Sh
        Dim c As Long
        .Name = Format(Date, "mmm yyyy")
        With .Cells(1, 1).Resize(6, Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)))
            .Formula = "=DATE(" & Year(Date) & ", " & Month(Date) & ", COLUMN())"
            .Value = .Value
            .Rows(1).NumberFormat = "d"
            .Rows(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).NumberFormat = "ddd"
            .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 5 'AutoFit
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                With .FormatConditions
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ROW()>2, WEEKDAY(A2, 15)>2)"
                    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=WEEKDAY(A2, 15)<3"
                    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ROW()=2, WEEKDAY(A2, 15)>2)"
                End With
                .FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = ";;;"
                .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = 5287936
                .FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = 14281213
            End With
        End With
        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 1
            .FreezePanes = True
            .Zoom = 80
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

You will likely want to make adjustments but this may be a good framework to get started. I've taken the approach of using the actual dates and displying their day-of-the-month and day-of-the-week through cell [Number Format Code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)s. This leaves the raw underlying date value(s) available for calculation and lookup. Similarly, the dates that appear blank are not actually blank; the custom number format that has been applied through [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) simply shows no value at all in the cell.

[image: auto_calendar]

Comment: Hi Jeeped, is a great way to use, I really appreciate great effort and excellent and professionalism  in developing the request information. can you please if you do not mind assist correcting the code I give as it is an example for what i want to use. the table I give is a part of annual leave. so your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are two other answers that provide corrections to your code. If those are not working, you should address those submissions directly. This was offered as an alternative; not as a repair to your original code. If it is of no use to you, just disregard it.

Comment: no, it is good to be used by me in other sheet such as timesheet. thanks Jeeped.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to part of the question, but I need help to complete the code as it applies to one row only.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()       
 Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Set rng = Range("A2:AE2")
 For Each cell In rng
   If Cells(2, cell.Column) = "Fri" Then
     Cells(3, cell.Column) = "Fri"
   ElseIf Cells(2, cell.Column) = "Sat" Then
     Cells(3, cell.Column) = "Sat"
   End If
 Next cell
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```